# Express: How to pass app-instance to routes from a different file?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to split up my routes into different files, where one file contains all routes and the other one the corresponding actions. I currently have a solution to achieve this, however I need to make the app-instance global to be able to access it in the actions.
My current setup looks like this:

app.js:

```
var express   = require('express');
var app       = express.createServer();
var routes    = require('./routes');

var controllers = require('./controllers');
routes.setup(app, controllers);

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Application is listening on port 3000');
});
```

routes.js:

```
exports.setup = function(app, controllers) {

  app.get('/', controllers.index);
  app.get('/posts', controllers.posts.index);
  app.get('/posts/:post', controllers.posts.show);
  // etc.

};
```

controllers/index.js:

```
exports.posts = require('./posts');

exports.index = function(req, res) {
  // code
};
```

controllers/posts.js:

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
  // code
};

exports.show = function(req, res) {
  // code
};
```

However, this setup has a big issue: I have a database- and an app-instance I need to pass to the actions (controllers/*.js). The only option I could think of, is making both variables global which isn't really a solution. I want to separate routes from the actions because I have a lot of routes and want them in a central place.

What's the best way to pass variables to the actions but separate the actions from the routes?

Comment: How does your controllers.js look like? Maybe you can make it a function (instead of an object) that can receive parameters.

Comment: require('controllers') requires controllers/index.js. However, a function won't work because I use the object in the routes (see routes.js) and thus can't pass arguments to it, even if it's a function.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Use `req.app`, `req.app.get('somekey')`

The application variable created by calling `express()` is set on the request and response objects.

See: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/76147c78a15904d4e4e469095a29d1bec9775ab6/lib/express.js#L34-L35

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the best way of accessing variables set with app.set('name', val);

Comment: Don't forget to call `app.set('somekey', {})` in app.js

Comment: My only gripe about this way though I do love it is that when you are trying to run an app.locals.authorized as such (not in main.js): `app.route('/something').get(app.locals.authorized,function(req,res,next){});` is not possible because it's outside the req scope.

Comment: I am using different passport strategy for different query parameter. So I am trying to set passport.use("strategy-name") in a middleware. Even if I store passport in that middleware only with let passport = req.app,get('passport'). It is being modified for another set of requests. Why is it so ?

Comment: If i do this, then req object will have addition Object instances like redis and db in my case. Won't it effect application performance ?
eg: 
in index.js
app.set('redis',redis_client);
in routes/example.js
router = require('express').Router();
route.get('/test',(req,res,next)=>{
   conosle.log(req.app.get('redis'));
   return res.send("//done");
})

Answer (score 105):

**Node.js supports circular dependencies.**
Making use of circular dependencies instead of require('./routes')(app) cleans up a lot of code and makes each module less interdependent on its loading file:

---

app.js

```
var app = module.exports = express(); //now app.js can be required to bring app into any file

//some app/middleware setup, etc, including 
app.use(app.router);

require('./routes'); //module.exports must be defined before this line
```

---

routes/index.js

```
var app = require('../app');

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});

//require in some other route files...each of which requires app independently
require('./user');
require('./blog');
```

---

**-----04/2014 update-----**
Express 4.0 fixed the usecase for defining routes by adding an express.router() method!

documentation - http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router

Example from their new generator:
Writing the route: 
https://github.com/expressjs/generator/blob/master/templates/js/routes/index.js

Adding/namespacing it to the app:
https://github.com/expressjs/generator/blob/master/templates/js/app.js#L24

There are still usecases for accessing app from other resources, so circular dependencies are still a valid solution.

Comment: "less interdependent on it's loading file" - it's dependent on the specific *filepath* of its loading file. That's very tight coupling, so let's not pretend it's not.

Comment: Just be very careful (read: don't do what I've been struggling with for the past hour+) that in `app.js` you require the routing file _after_ exporting the app. Circular `require()` calls can make for a real mess, so be sure you know [how they work](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_cycles)!

Comment: I honestly think that the answer from @Feng about using req.app.get('somekey') is indeed a way better and cleaner solution than using circulr dependencies.

Comment: @Green if app is empty, you required a file that required `app` BEFORE app `module.exports` was defined.  You have to instantiate `app`, set `module.exports`, then require files that might require `app`  But either way, doing the circular dependencies is an anti-pattern that express has solved - you shouldn't need to do that anymore.

Answer (score 26):

Like I said in the comments, you can use a function as module.exports. A function is also an object, so you don't have to change your syntax.

app.js

```
var controllers = require('./controllers')({app: app});
```

controllers.js

```
module.exports = function(params)
{
    return require('controllers/index')(params);
}
```

controllers/index.js

```
function controllers(params)
{
  var app = params.app;

  controllers.posts = require('./posts');

  controllers.index = function(req, res) {
    // code
  };
}

module.exports = controllers;
```

Comment: Is it OK to return an object inside the function or is it better so set the methods the way you do in your example?

Comment: i think either approach is ok.

Comment: Because I have a lot of methods, I'd prefer to set them as an object instead of each manually. This would work when I just return the object, but isn't there a solution which is a bit flatter? My actual methods would be indented twice...

Comment: Not sure if I understood you, but I guess you could move the implementation outside that `controllers` function, something like: http://jsfiddle.net/mihaifm/yV79K/

Comment: does not controllers/index.js need to return controllers var?

Answer (score 6):

Or just do that:

```
var app = req.app
```

inside the Middleware you are using for these routes. Like that:

```
router.use( (req,res,next) => {
    app = req.app;
    next();
});
```

Comment: Someone tell me why this is not the accepted answer? For dependencies you use `app.use('my-service', serviceInstance)` in the main router and `req.app.get('my-service')` in the controller as mentioned by @Feng

Comment: if you use `var app = req.app` in `myMiddlewareFile.js` and 'update it' with something like `app.locals.mongodb_client = mongdb_client`, do you need to export `app` from that file to make that property accessible to the rest of the middleware files?  or is `app` updated 'globally' from that assignment?

Answer (score 2):

1. To make your db object accessible to all controllers without passing it everywhere: make an application-level middleware which attachs the db object to every req object, then you can access it within in every controller.

```js
// app.js
let db = ...;  // your db object initialized
const contextMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  req.db=db;
  next();
};
app.use(contextMiddleware);
```

2. to avoid passing app instance everywhere, instead, passing routes to where the app is

```js
// routes.js  It's just a mapping.
exports.routes = [
  ['/', controllers.index],
  ['/posts', controllers.posts.index],
  ['/posts/:post', controllers.posts.show]
];

// app.js
var { routes }    = require('./routes');
routes.forEach(route => app.get(...route));
// You can customize this according to your own needs, like adding post request
```

The final app.js:

```js
// app.js
var express   = require('express');
var app       = express.createServer();

let db = ...;  // your db object initialized
const contextMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  req.db=db;
  next();
};
app.use(contextMiddleware);

var { routes }    = require('./routes');
routes.forEach(route => app.get(...route));

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Application is listening on port 3000');
});
```

Another version: you can customize this according to your own needs, like adding post request

```js
// routes.js  It's just a mapping.
let get = ({path, callback}) => ({app})=>{
  app.get(path, callback);
}
let post = ({path, callback}) => ({app})=>{
  app.post(path, callback);
}
let someFn = ({path, callback}) => ({app})=>{
  // ...custom logic
  app.get(path, callback);
}
exports.routes = [
  get({path: '/', callback: controllers.index}),
  post({path: '/posts', callback: controllers.posts.index}),
  someFn({path: '/posts/:post', callback: controllers.posts.show}),
];

// app.js
var { routes }    = require('./routes');
routes.forEach(route => route({app}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you have a folder named "contollers".

In your app.js you can put this code:

```
console.log("Loading controllers....");
var controllers = {};

var controllers_path = process.cwd() + '/controllers'

fs.readdirSync(controllers_path).forEach(function (file) {
    if (file.indexOf('.js') != -1) {
        controllers[file.split('.')[0]] = require(controllers_path + '/' + file)
    }
});

console.log("Controllers loaded..............[ok]");
```

... and ...

```
router.get('/ping', controllers.ping.pinging);
```

in your controllers forlder you will have the file "ping.js" with this code:

```
exports.pinging = function(req, res, next){
    console.log("ping ...");
}
```

And this is it....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass an app-instance to others in **Node-Typescript** :

**Option 1:**
With the help of `import` (**when importing**)

```
//routes.ts
import { Application } from "express";
import { categoryRoute } from './routes/admin/category.route'
import { courseRoute } from './routes/admin/course.route';

const routing = (app: Application) => {
    app.use('/api/admin/category', categoryRoute)
    app.use('/api/admin/course', courseRoute)
}
export { routing }
```

Then import it and pass app:

```
import express, { Application } from 'express';

const app: Application = express();
import('./routes').then(m => m.routing(app))
```

**Option 2**: With the help of `class`

```
// index.ts
import express, { Application } from 'express';
import { Routes } from './routes';


const app: Application = express();
const rotues = new Routes(app)
...
```

Here we will access the app in the constructor of Routes Class

```
// routes.ts
import { Application } from 'express'
import { categoryRoute } from '../routes/admin/category.route'
import { courseRoute } from '../routes/admin/course.route';

class Routes {
    constructor(private app: Application) {
        this.apply();
    }

    private apply(): void {
       this.app.use('/api/admin/category', categoryRoute)
       this.app.use('/api/admin/course', courseRoute)
    }
}

export { Routes }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require('express');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   console.log(req.app); // use req.app to get app instance ;

   res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });

});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Please add context around code-only answers

Answer (score -1):

For database separate out Data Access Service that will do all DB work with simple API and avoid shared state.

Separating routes.setup looks like overhead. I would prefer to place a configuration based routing instead. And configure routes in .json or with annotations.

Comment: What do you mean with a Data Access Service? How would it look like?

Comment: My real routes.js file is much bigger and uses the express-namespaces module. How would you separate the routes from the actions?