# Express-resource pass additional data from app.js to routes

Tags: node.js, express, express-resource

I would like to pass additional data from app.js to express-resource routes and I have not figured out yet. How would you do that? Note that I'm using express-resource

```
// app.js
var myAddOnData = 'abc';
app.resource('users', './routes/user');

// user.js
exports.index = function (req, res) {
   console.log(myAddOnData);
};
```

Thanks

Comment: I saw people use init function but I'm not sure express-resource will have a better solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030521/pass-variable-to-expresjs-3-routes?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

These are the three approaches I can think of. Without the little I know about your specific problem, it sounds like middleware might be the way to do it.

#### With a global `app` variable

Create a value using [`app.set`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.set) in `app.js` and then retrieve it using [`app.get`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.get) in `user.js`.

#### Using a module

Store the information in an isolated module, then `require()` as needed. If this is running across multiple instances, you'd obviously want to store the values to disk as opposed to in memory.

```js
// keystore.js
// -----------
module.exports.set = function(id, val) { /* ... */ };
module.exports.get = function(id) { /* ... */ };


// app.js
// -----------
var ks = require('./keystore');
ks.set = function("userInfo", "abc");
module.exports.get = function(id) { /* ... */ };


// user.js
// -----------
var ks = require('./keystore');
ks.get = function("userInfo", "abc");
```

(Maybe check out [pot](https://github.com/carlosdavidepto/pot)?)

#### Using Middleware

Use custom middleware to attach data to the request object which can then be accessed later in the route handlers.

```js
//app.js
//------
var express = require('express')
  , cookieSessions = require('./cookie-sessions');

var app = express();

app.use(express.cookieParser('manny is cool'));
app.use(cookieSessions('sid'));
// ...

//cookie-sessions.js
//------------------
module.exports = function(name) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    req.session = req.signedCookies[name] || {};

    res.on('header', function(){
      res.signedCookie(name, req.session, { signed: true });
    });

    next();
  }
}
```

via https://gist.github.com/visionmedia/1491756

Comment: this will require app to be global and I'm not sure this is the best practice. I'm running my app using cluster for multi processes, using global will screw me up badly.

Comment: Almost every express example I have seen uses a global `app` var, but you could just as easily wrap your main application (`app`) using the module pattern and the `get`/`set` approach should still work then. Or you could probably also get away with a straight key/value store module. If that's not your style, you could try writing some custom middleware to inject the values.