# How to mount express.js sub-apps over uri with parameter

Tags: node.js, express, subapplication

I'd like to be able to mount a whole express sub-app on a uri containing a parameter. I've something similar to the following:

in app.js:

```
var app_authors = require('./api/authors');
var app = express();
...
app.use('/api/authors', app_authors);
...
module.exports = app;
```

in api/authors.js:

```
var app_author_books = require('./api/books');
var app = express();
...
app.get('/:author', ...);
...
app.use('/:author/books', app_author_books);
...
module.exports = app;
```

While the first sub-app works, mounted over `/api/authors`, the nested one doesn't (urls of the form `/api/authors/:author/books` and similar are not recognized)

EDIT:

For the curious, AFAIK sub-apps are not very clearly documented, but they should work, at least according to [TJ Holowaychuk's Modular web applications with Node.js and Express](http://tjholowaychuk.com/post/38571504626/modular-web-applications-with-node-js-and-express) (and the related vimeo [screencast](http://vimeo.com/56166857)). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8514234/1363486) other SO answer.

Comment: try defining the `app_author_books` function inline instead of requiring `./api/authors`. also try adding a trailing slash to the path in app.js at `app.use('/api/authors', app_authors);`

Comment: @Plato while that would likely work, it seems that your answer is just avoiding the main question. While it would be fine to write it inline (or reference a function) for one route, it is cumbersome if `app_author_books` contains multiple routes (perhaps a RESTful interface for all books).

Comment: what @NickMitchinson says is correct: app_author_books is a sub-app, containing many routes

Comment: well, as [docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use) mention, the sub-apps don't see the prefix. could you swap 'em? in app.js: `app.use('/books/', app_author_books)`; and in authors.js: `app.get('/:author', function(){...}` with new path `/api/books/:author`

Comment: regarding the visibility of the prefix, you are right, but I'm using [app.param()](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.param) to populate `req` with the object derived from `:author`, so this limitation is a non-issue. And unfortunately I can't swap the sub-apps (because the inner one is dependent on the author object instance...)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to create different "applications" to separate the routes/services in different files.

You should try the approach given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090414/express-how-to-pass-app-instance-to-routes-from-a-different-file)
in which they pass the app variable as a **parameter**, and hence, you only have one application that controls all the routes (that are located in your separate files).

I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm aware of that approach, but I'd really like to use sub-apps instead of a single giant app. sub-apps are supported by express, see for example [Modular web applications with Node.js and Express](http://vimeo.com/56166857) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8514234/1363486) SO answer.

Comment: Oh, sorry...I interpreted the question wrong. Time for me to study more Express sub-apps!

Answer (score 0):

In Express 4, when you mount a sub-app on a path (or a regex), this path is removed from req.path (but is still in req.originalUrl).

See this [github issue](https://github.com/strongloop/express/issues/2608) and Express 4 doc about mountpoints.

Comment: Good. I didn't look much at express 4 yet, but it seems that it has a much better routing finally. Thank you for the heads up.