# Structuring a MEAN app so Express can find all the Jade files

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, module, pug

I am building out a MEAN app right now that is getting big. I really need to start modularizing the app but right now my Express server is configured to look for Jade views in one folder

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/app/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

The authors of these posts show the view files scattered about the app in the different module directories.

- https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/03/27/13-step-guide-angularjs-modularization/
- http://www.johnpapa.net/angular-app-structuring-guidelines/

If I try to do this now, my Express server will not be able to see them. How can I make it so Express will be able to find all the Jade views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Two solutions :

- You can use a base folder named `views` and create subfolders inside `views`.
  For example, `views/menu/`, `views/header/`. To use this, you have to
  declare a `basedir` in Express so Jade will know where to look your
  views, by doing `app.locals.basedir = __dirname + "/views";`. Then,
  in your Jade file, use `include /header/a.jade`, `include
  /menu/item1.jade` etc...
- Use Express App submounting feature. This allows you to modularize
  your main app into small apps, which all have their own routes, views
  etc... You can watch this [nice video tutorial by TJ
  Holowaychuk](http://vimeo.com/56166857) to learn more about this.

Does that help you ?

Comment: I decided to go with the Express submounting feature which works fine. I still don't fully understand how it works with the whole circular dependency thing as talked about in this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21103523/883807 but I'll figure it out eventually. Thanks Waldo :)

Answer (score 0):

I just start using module prefixes in my render calls and set my views base directory to be the parent directory of my modules. So if I started with:

```
app/views/page1.jade
app/views/page2.jade
```

and was doing `res.render("page1")`, I reorganize to:

```
app/module1/page1.jade
app/module2/page2.jade
```

and I do `app.set("views", "app")` then render with `res.render("module1/page1")`.

Comment: I created around 20 different module folders for my app with controllers, views and a module.js file in each. So you are saying for each of these folders I will have to do a `res.render()` on it to be able to render the view? e.g. for the signup module, `res.render("signup/signup")` in which the first `signup` in the path refers to the module folder and the second `signup` in the path refers to `signup.jade`

Comment: Yes, that's right. Of course, if you have a lot of pages and this becomes a clear pattern, you can extract a middleware that will automatically render the correct template based on the URL path if you like. I often don't have a 1-1 mapping of URL paths to template paths though.