# app.set and then TypeError: app.get is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

While using express 4.x, I am setting the port in my server.js like in the following.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
...
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.set('port', port);
...
module.exports = app;
```

But when I try to access it within my routes file, like the following...

```
// path to routes file is app/models, hence the '../../'
var app = require('../../server');

// default route
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello! The API is at http://localhost:' + app.get('port') + '/api');
});
```

... I get the following error.

```
TypeError: app.get is not a function
```

What on earth is going on?

Comment: Did you try `app.address().port`

Comment: Other thing: `app.set` can only used for these parameters:http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.set   and http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.settings.table

Comment: @BlackMamba I am not sure about that, because the express documents have explicitly given an example of setting a custom variable called 'title' and then retrieved it using app.get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I have finally figured it out. The `app` was not properly being set within the routes file because we were previously doing `module.exports = app` after `require('./app/models/routes');` within server.js. So as soon as I moved the exporting of the app to happen before the requiring of the routes file... everything worked!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what's going on and I don't know if you would like this solution. I had a similar problem as this once.

in the main file i did something like

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
....
var routes = require("./routes/path")
routes(app);
```

and in routes i did something like

in where you have "./routes/path" file:

```
module.exports = function(app){
   //I got access to app.locals
}
```

you see I passed along the express app .

basically routes is a function that takes app as a parameter.

I tried app.set("app", app) and I don't think that worked.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like app is not being defined. you could also try something like this.

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var app =req.app.get("app")
    res.send('Hello! The API is at http://localhost:' + app.get("port") + '/api');
});
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15018006/1893672

Comment: why isn't it being defined? I have seen examples on the internet where `module.exports = app` has been recommended. So why doesn't it work in this circumstance ?

Answer (score 0):

In your route handling for GET, POST, etc, you should be receiving the 'req' dependency. App should be attached to this so just reference req.app:

```
router.get('/',function(req,res,next){
    console.log(app.get('secret'));
}
```

No require statement should be necessary.