# Error in express app when changing from .use(req,res) to using a routes.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, typeerror

I have a site in express and am trying to convert it to use a routes.js file to clean things up. I am getting a TypeError, explained below. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40828932/typeerror-app-get-is-not-a-function) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547614/app-set-and-then-typeerror-app-get-is-not-a-function) but I still can't figure it out. Currently the site works with the following lines:

```
const server = express()
    .set('view engine', 'ejs') // set up ejs for templating
    .use(flash()) // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session
  .use((req, res) => res.render('../views/pages/indextimewithall.ejs', {stockSearched :"X",
                     activeStocks: [],
                    addingError:false}) )
  .listen(port);


const wss = new SocketServer({ server });

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
  console.log('Client connected');
  ws.on('close', () => console.log('Client disconnected'));
});

setInterval(() => {
  wss.clients.forEach((client) => {
    client.send(new Date().toTimeString());
  });
}, 1000);
```

But when I change it to this:

```
const server = express()

.set('view engine', 'ejs') // set up ejs for templating
        .use(flash()) // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session
      .listen(port);
    require('./app/routes.js')(server); 

    const wss = new SocketServer({ server });

    wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
      console.log('Client connected');
      ws.on('close', () => console.log('Client disconnected'));
    });

    setInterval(() => {
      wss.clients.forEach((client) => {
        client.send(new Date().toTimeString());
      });
    }, 1000);
```

..I get the TypeError: app.get is not a function

Here are the contents of routes.js file:

```
// app/routes.js
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        var myStocks = require('./models/myStock'); 
        var showStocks = function(err, data){
            res.render('pages/indextimewithall.ejs', {
                     stockSearched :"X",
                    activeStocks: [],
                    addingError:false
                });
        }
        myStocks.find({isActive:true}).exec(showStocks);
    });
};
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your clean up is just fine (although the readability and maintainability is a big issue...).  Here is a big gotcha for you:

`app.listen` method is not chainable, but `app.use` or `app.METHOD` series are.  This means this method is not return itself at the end.  Therefore, you will get `app.get` is undefined, because your `server` variable is not an express instance.

What you should do is break the chain, and defined as the following:

```
const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');     // set up ejs for templating
app.use(flash());                  // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session
require('./app/routes.js')(app);   // not recommended to clean up like this way though
app.listen(port);


const wss = new SocketServer({ server: app });
wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
  console.log('Client connected');
  ws.on('close', () => console.log('Client disconnected'));
});


setInterval(() => {
  wss.clients.forEach((client) => {
    client.send(new Date().toTimeString());
  });
}, 1000);
```

Note, in the above, I renamed your variable `server` as `app`. Just to follow the convention.

You can know if a method is chainable by running something like this:

```
const app = express();
console.log(app === app.use((req, res, next) => next)));  // true
console.log(app === app.listen(3000));  // false
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason now the setInterval() isn't working though (the action it's taking isn't appearing) any ideas why?

Comment: That is because you load it from a separate file...  If you load the module via ES6 `import/export`, then `setInterval` will working.  The reason behind it is very complicated. For more information, you can google it.  Here is a quick [reference](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/an-update-on-es6-modules-in-node-js-42c958b890c) on the status of implementing the ES6 module loading. And it is currently available in the experimental mode.

Comment: I believe you can still kick the function defined in `setInterval` working, and you will have to make some change to let it happened, but I'm not sure about the details to do it, you can give it a try.

Comment: Thank you, I got it to work by replacing app.listen(port) with const server = app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ port }`)); and then writing just 'server' instead of 'server: app' I really appreciate all your help! I am still learning the conventions around organization too - always trying to improve on that...