# How to pass app object to a module?

Tags: node.js, express

My server.js is:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var login = require('login');
app.use('/login', login);
```

In my login.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login.jade');
});

module.exports = router;
```

How can I pass the `app` object in server.js to the scope of login.js?

Can I just instantiate `var app = express();` in login.js and use that instead?  Will then there be two different instances of `app`?

Comment: Related: [Express: How to pass app-instance to routes from a different file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090414/express-how-to-pass-app-instance-to-routes-from-a-different-file)

Comment: Thanks.  This is exactly what I was seeking.  Tested and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

You can either `export` it on server.js or make it a `global` or pass it as a parameter.

```
export app;
import { app } from './server';
```

or

```
global.app = app;
```

or:

```
app.use('/login', login(app));
```

login.js

```
function(app) {
   // login stuff here
}
```

Comment: I want to organize the login stuff using `passport` in login.js, and that requires a few middleware items.

Comment: @OldGeezer uhm, okay. I don't like using `app` anywhere but in the main file.

Comment: @OldGeezer added a third option

Comment: Thanks, but the link provided by Josh Crozier above is what I need. I also notice that the Visual Studio template for a Node.js Express app uses that same method.

Answer (score 2):

in ES6(ecmascript6):

```
server.js
export const app = express()

login.js
import { app } from '../server'
```

in ES5:

```
server.js
module.exports: {
  app: express()
}

login.js
var app = require('path').app
```

Answer (score 1):

In your server.js just use `require('login')(app);`

In your login.js:-

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('login.jade');
    });
};
```